# Analyzing Repeated Measurements with Single Outcome: Choosing the Right Statistical Model

Tags: r, regression, time-series, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I'm encountering a slight issue with my dataset, and I'd like to provide some context: I have a dataset with 1600 patients, and we've been monitoring their glucose levels on a weekly basis over a period of 30 weeks. Additionally, at the end of the 30 weeks, we conducted a unique blood test for each patient. Currently, I'm attempting to explore the association between these repeated glucose level measures and the final outcome. I'm aware that using models like Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) and Mixed Models might not be suitable because I only have a single measurement of the dependent variable for each participant.

I have a few questions in this regard. First, should I treat different glucose measures at various time points (e.g., at day 10, day 20, etc.) as separate variables? If so, how can I account for the correlation between these measures?

It has crossed my mind that I could use a GEE model while clustering for time and determining a correlation matrix to capture the association between these repeated measures. However, I'm uncertain if this is the appropriate model for my analysis.

Your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Regression doesn't assume that the predictors are uncorrelated, so *blood_test ~ x1 + ... + x30* seems a reasonable start. If you'd like the reduce the correlation between the glucose measurements, xi, then you can subtract the earliest measurements from the rest: *blood_test ~ x1 + (x2-x1) + (x30-x1)*. Without an intervention (not mentioned in the question), I would expect there is no trend in glucose levels over those 30 weeks.